# Cannot set property 'employeeNum' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a function that is meant to add an employee to the end of a list of employees, but I continue to be met with the error in the title. I've tried to alter the code, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the function:

data-service.js

```
   module.exports.addEmployee = function(employeeData) {
        employeeData.employeeNum = ++empCount;
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            employees.push(employeeData);
            if(employees.length == 0) {
                reject("no results returned");
            }
            resolve(employeeData);
        });
    }
```

server.js

```
app.get("/employees/add", (req,res) => {
    res.render("addEmployee");
});

app.post("/employees/add", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect("/employees");
});
```

Comment: Would need to see more of the code. Is employeeData variable undefined?  Where does the variable `employees` come from?

Comment: Are you calling `addEmployee` with `null` or `undefined` or just empty? Basically anything other than an object?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more

Comment: employeeData is a parameter belonging to the new method addEmployee(employeeData). It's meant to act as the object that will be passed to the file containing the employee objects.

Answer (score 0):

The current function is not the root of the problem... However, you are trying to set a property on a param that you expect to be an object. But the caller has either passed a variable that has a `value === undefined`, or perhaps is passing no params at all ( either way, the param `employeeData` is undefined and you have no checks against it, thus we see the error).